# Auto bottom scroll div jquery in a MDL framework page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have this quistion about scrolling in a div with the MDL framework

**THE GOAL** *is to scroll to the bottom of the div after 4 seconds*

This is my jquery:

```
  $('#user-select').on('change', function() {
  $("html, body").delay(4000).animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 1000);});
```

I also tried this:

```
 $('#user-select').on('change', function() {
setInterval(function() { $('#chat').animate({scrollTop: $('#chat').height()}, 1000); },4000);});
```

This is my html:

```
 <div style="width:100%;" id="chat_box">
                    <div id="chat">

                </div>
                </div>
```

The content of the div loads via a AJAX Request

The final code looks like this:

```
   <div style="width:100%;" id="chat_box">
                        <div id="chat">
    <div class="bubble right">
            <div class="content">
    Test 1</div>

    </div>

        <div class="bubble left">
            <div class="content">
        Test 1
</div>
        </div>
     </div>
    </div>
```

I have tried multiple options for scrolling down in divs with jquery but none of them worked

Thanks A lot!!

Comment: So where's the element with id `user-select`? And if you want to scroll "inside a div" (meaning the div itself has a scrollbar?), then animate the property on that element, and not html and body instead.

Comment: setInterval(function() {
 $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $('html,body').height()}, 1000);
},4000);

Comment: @CBroe The div has a scroll bar, the user-select is in my full code but the problem is not in that piece because on change the ajax function starts running and that works fine.

Comment: @FernandoUrban I tried your code but this doesnt work either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out how:

Jquery

```
  var scrollTo = function(top) {
      var content = $(".mdl-layout__content");
      var target = top ? 0 : $(".page-content").height();
      content.stop().animate({ scrollTop: target }, 3000);
    };

var scrollToTop = function() {
  scrollTo(true);
};

var scrollToBottom = function() {
  scrollTo(false);
};
```

And than call the function after 4 seconds

```
setTimeout(scrollToBottom, 4000)
```

Thanks to [MDLHUT on CodePen](http://codepen.io/mdlhut/pen/BNeoVa)